# Is there an equivalent to fontspec's Scale=MatchUppercase for pdflatex? Or how to find out the best scale for two fonts?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, scaling

I am using `XCharter` and `tgheroes`. Although I do not use the sans in running text, I'd like to scale it accordingly.

Is there any other way than just to do some T&E with the settings? Fontspec's options are really handy in that regard (the ones I know, at least).

I think what the issue is actually based on... which measure does the `scale`-option for TeX Gyre Heros scale?

("spoiler": the best value for the code below seems to be 0.9)

### Picture of MWE output

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=12pt,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\KOMAoptions{fontsize=11pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmath}
%
\usepackage[scale=0.96]{tgheros}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter,expert]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[sups]{XCharter}
\usepackage{beramono}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\verb+AAaa\textsf{aaAA}AA+ & AAaa\textsf{aaAA}AA\\
\bfseries\verb+AAaa\textsf{aaAA}AA+ & \bfseries AAaa\textsf{aaAA}AA\\
\verb+XXxx\textsf{xxXX}XXxx+ & XXxx\textsf{xxXX}XXxx\\
\bfseries \verb+XXxx\textsf{xxXX}XXxx+ & \bfseries XXxx\textsf{xxXX}XXxx\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
Something else:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{x=3}^{12} \sin(x) \cdot \pi
\end{equation}
\end{document}}
```

Comment: No, not really. :( Note that `fontspec` has a “centralized” font loading mechanism, while font packages for `pdflatex` have several different quirks. For instance, some have the `scale` option, others have `scaled` and the greatest part has neither. If a `scale(d)` option is not supported, one has essentially to rewrite the `.fd` file inside the document.

Comment: @egreg Ok. :/ Imho your comment answers the issue so if you submit it as a reply, I could mark it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general this is quite difficult to attain, because each font package has different ideas; for instance, some packages have the `scale` options, others have `scaled`, most have neither.

In your case you're lucky, because both `tgheros` and `beramono` support scaling, the former with `scale`, the latter with `scaled`.

The simplest way is to prepare a document such as

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=11pt}

\usepackage[bitstream-charter,expert]{mathdesign}
\expandafter\let\csname T1+fvm\endcsname\relax
\usepackage[sups]{XCharter}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{tgheros}


\begin{document}
\sbox0{A}Charter: \the\ht0

\sbox0{\ttfamily A}Beramono: \the\ht0

\sbox0{\sffamily A}heros: \the\ht0
\end{document}
```

You get

[image]

Now you know that Beramono and TeX Gyre Heros have to be scaled down. How much? Use a pocket calculator:

```
7.40767/8.17964 ≈ 0.9056
7.40767/8.10298 ≈ 0.9142
```

so you can do your scaling:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\KOMAoptions{fontsize=11pt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmath}
%

\usepackage[bitstream-charter,expert]{mathdesign}
\expandafter\let\csname T1+fvm\endcsname\relax
\usepackage[sups]{XCharter}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9056]{beramono}
\usepackage[scale=0.9142]{tgheros}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
A{\ttfamily A}\\
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\verb+AAaa\textsf{aaAA}AA+ & AAaa\textsf{aaAA}AA\\
\bfseries\verb+AAaa\textsf{aaAA}AA+ & \bfseries AAaa\textsf{aaAA}AA\\
\verb+XXxx\textsf{xxXX}XXxx+ & XXxx\textsf{xxXX}XXxx\\
\bfseries \verb+XXxx\textsf{xxXX}XXxx+ & \bfseries XXxx\textsf{xxXX}XXxx\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Why the strange `\expandafter\let\csname T1+fvm\endcsname\relax`?**

The `mathdesign` package has its own ideas about what's the right scaling of Bera Mono. That instruction makes LaTeX think it doesn't.

Comment: @cfr Yes, sorry! I didn't fix the text after finally discovering why BeraMono wasn't scaled at all.

Comment: ...after all these years I wondered why Bera Mono wasn't scaled properly and values larger than 1 did not have any effect. Turns out I lost that particular line `\expandafter\let\csname T1+fvm\endcsname\relax` at some point in the last years. And then through some googling, found my own question again...