# Scale math font with newtxsf

Tags: fonts, pdftex, scaling

I'm using uarial as text font and want to use newtxsf as a nearly matching math font. I scaled uarial to match the height of latin modern as described in this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206677.

Still I'm encountering two problems:

- I don't know how to scale newtxsf correctly, since \the\ht0 stays the same when I change the scaled option. If there is no way to display the height directly I would try some values and choose the one that fits the most.
- in math mode, "sin", "cos", ... are not set in uarial but in latin modern. Is there a way to tell newtxsf to use \sffamily instead of \rmfamily? I tried to solve this using the newtxsf documentation but failed. Or is there another package that matched uarial?

My Code so far

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[scale=0.93]{tgheros}
\usepackage[scaled=1]{newtxsf}
 
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Displaying height of fonts}\par
    \sbox0{\sffamily A}heros: \the\ht0 \\
    \sbox0{\rmfamily A}latin modern: \the\ht0\\
    \sbox0{\ttfamily A}newtxsf: \the\ht0\par
    \textbf{Math mode}  $ Q = P\tan(\varphi)$
\end{document}
```

Compiled Document:
[image: Compiled document]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My suggestion is to try with no scaling; in this case we get the height of a sans serif A is 8.87999pt and the height of a math A is 8.148pt.

Therefore the scaling factor is 8.148/8.87999=0.91757 (rounded to the fifth decimal digit). Now with

```latex
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[scale=.91757]{tgheros}
\usepackage[scaled=1]{newtxsf}

\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{\sfdefault}

% this to get the operators in the sans serif font
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

    \textbf{Displaying height of fonts}

    \sbox0{\sffamily A}heros: \the\ht0

    \sbox0{$A$}newtxsf: \the\ht0

    \textbf{Math mode}  $ Q = P\tan(\varphi)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Note that, in `unicode-math`, the solution is `Scale=MatchLowercase`, or sometimes, `Scale=MatchUppercase`.  You can even set it as `\defaultfontfeatures`.

It also sets the main font as both the operator font and the `\mathrm` font, but you can override this, with `\setoperatorfont`, `\setmathrm`, etc.